# Usar variables dentro de una expresión regular en JMETER

Tags: regex, variables, jmeter

Estoy  tratando de  correlacionar  paginas  en  Jmeter, necesito  extraer un valor de un response  mediante una expresión regular pero el patrón es dinámico.  He  intentado de diferentes maneras pero sin lograrlo. espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Les agradezco de antemano.

Cadena pura en response

```
zTaskId=13733\">B2313-656-1
```

Expresiones regulares mas variable que no me funcionan

```
zTaskId=(.+?)\">${dyn_Folio}
```

```
zTaskId=(.+?)\">\$\{dyn_Folio\}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para coincidir con una `\`, en el patrón se usa `\\`.

```
zTaskId=(.+?)\\">\$\{dyn_Folio\}
```

Una barra sirve para escapar al siguiente caracter. De esa forma, usaste bien `\$` para que no se interprete como "final del texto". Pero habías utilizado `\"`, que incluso cuando las comillas no tienen un significado especial, `\"` coincide con el texto: `"`.